# Loop including 0 R

Tags: r, loops

I create the following range:

```
x <- seq(0,22)
```

Now I want to get some expected poisson estimations:

```
for (val in x) {
  vec[val]<-(dpois(val,6.298387))*124
}
```

I want also the estimation for val = 0

```
(dpois(0,6.298387))*124
```

However, the vector "vec" obtained previously starts at val = 1.

How can I force the loop to take also values = 0?

Comment: `vec[val + 1] <- (dpois(val,6.298387))*124`

Comment: `vec[0]` means "no entries in `val`".  In R, indexing starts at 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since R is 1-indexed, there is no such thing as `vec[0]`. The first valid index of `vec` is `vec[1]`, so you probably intended

```r
x <- seq(0,22)

vec <- numeric()

for (val in x) {
  vec[val + 1] <- dpois(val, 6.298387) * 124
} 

vec
#>  [1] 2.280694e-01 1.436469e+00 4.523719e+00 9.497378e+00 1.495454e+01
#>  [6] 1.883790e+01 1.977473e+01 1.779270e+01 1.400816e+01 9.803203e+00
#> [11] 6.174437e+00 3.535363e+00 1.855590e+00 8.990174e-01 4.044542e-01
#> [16] 1.698273e-01 6.685238e-02 2.476836e-02 8.666707e-03 2.872962e-03
#> [21] 9.047512e-04 2.713559e-04 7.768656e-05
```

However, the loop is not necessary, since `dpois` is vectorized like many R functions. Therefore the above code simplifies to this one-liner:

```r
dpois(0:22, 6.298387) * 124
#>  [1] 2.280694e-01 1.436469e+00 4.523719e+00 9.497378e+00 1.495454e+01
#>  [6] 1.883790e+01 1.977473e+01 1.779270e+01 1.400816e+01 9.803203e+00
#> [11] 6.174437e+00 3.535363e+00 1.855590e+00 8.990174e-01 4.044542e-01
#> [16] 1.698273e-01 6.685238e-02 2.476836e-02 8.666707e-03 2.872962e-03
#> [21] 9.047512e-04 2.713559e-04 7.768656e-05
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>